# Error initializing MongoEmbebbed. MongoClientSettings not found

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

I can't manage to get the Mongo Embebbed running. I'm using Spring Boot with Flapdoodle and jirutka

I'm not sure if there is a problem with the versions or what I need to change.
This is the log of the error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'chatController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'chatMessageService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'chatMessageService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'chatMessageRepository' defined in com.homecooking.repository.ChatMessageRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on HomeCookingBack: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongo' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoClientSettings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration$MongoClientSettingsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings]: Factory method 'mongoClientSettings' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/codecs/EnumCodecProvider
```

It seems that it can't configure properly the Mongo, as the problem narrows down to an error setting up the MongoClientSettings.

This is the Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bezkoder</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-security-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-security-jwt</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Security - JWT</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27018
spring.data.mongodb.database=homecooking-messaging
spring.mongodb.embedded.version=3.4.6
```

Link to the Repo for more information: https://github.com/NachoEstevo/HomeCooking-Client-Back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved updating all the dependencies to the most recent ones.

Always check every dependency and see if there is any issue. Most likely compatibility issues are solved on upgrades. This case was Spring boot 2.6.1 -> 2.7.1